# Select values based on multiple keys

Tags: mysql

I am New to sql

I have Select boxes on my page when a user selects from that boxes and click submit all of the info will be pulled from a single table with the given multiple select boxes values
is it possible to put multiple values in WHERE

Regards'Sajid

Comment: sure you can, something like, select * from thetable where `column1` = 'something' OR `column1`='abc' OR `column2` = `something`; Please post what you have tried so far or see a basic sql tutorial on w3schools

Answer (score 1):

You will need an `IN` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `column_name` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) -- comma separated list of values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a query like this (example):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE price < 80 
    AND price > 30
    AND comments IS NOT NULL
    AND category = 'snacks'
    AND ...
```